# Selecting rectangle box from raster tiled table in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster

I am new to PostGIS as well as SQL queries for rasters.

I have imported a raster .tif file into PostGIS 2.1 with tiles. I would need to select a bounded rectangle from within this raster using SQL statements but i have no clue on how to begin.

Can i ask what are the possible/better ways to do that?

Do i need to have the top left and bottom right coordinates/lat long to get the rectangle?

I had search and read many other related posts about using ST_Intersects, BBOX and ST_MakeEnvelope but i don't really quite get them.